# jQuery height() does not return the actual height but instead either 0, -2 or 2

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want an icon in front of a headline of various length, sometimes 1 line, sometimes 2 lines, the icon should resize to the height of of 1 or 2 lines.

Since the svg takes all the available space, it would always be as big as the .svg-container. The svgs of the icons are squared and thats what I want to achieve for their container .svg-container. It should have the same height like the .headline element, so this height also applies as a width of the .svg-container.

Therefore I would like to get the height of the .headline span (or should it be a div?) with `$('.headline').height();` and add the returned value to .svg-container via `.css()`.

But I don't get the real height, it returns 0. I tried to get heights of other elements on the page, but it either returns 0, -2 or 2.

I already found out that it needs a `$(document).ready(function(){` but that doesn't change a thing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var headlineHeight = $('.headline').height();
  $('.svg-container').css('width', headlineHeight)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="spacing-after headline-with-icon">
  <span class="svg-container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  viewBox="0 0 40 40" style="enable-background:new 0 0 40 40;" xml:space="preserve">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-1"/><!-- takes the icon form an svg sprite -->  
  </svg>
  </span>
  <span class="headline">Headline in here</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Maybe try adding a pixel measure to the value, like this: `$('.svg-container').css('width', headlineHeight + 'px')`

Comment: Try `display: block;` to `svg-container` or else use `div`

Comment: Try `console.log(headlineHeight);` and it gives you the correct value. Not sure what you are asking..

Comment: @YaakovAinspan no, no need with jQuery. Div will fix it.

Comment: @MiXT4PE I tried to get the value of the height through consol.log, thats how I found out, that it does not return the real height, it only returns 0 ... exchange the span of .headline through a div still returns 0

Comment: @fontispitz See my answer below. I don't encounter this problem using your code and using `console.log()`. Please post the rest of your code and I can see where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `.svg-container`-element from a `span` to a `div` as a `span` does not naturally accept a width. I also added `width: 100%;` so the svg complies with it's parents width and as you can see the svg gets smaller after the script ran. I threw in a `console.log()` for good measure as well.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let headlineHeight = $('.headline').height();
  
  console.log(headlineHeight);
  
  $('.svg-container').css('width', headlineHeight)
});
```

```css
.svg-container > svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="spacing-after headline-with-icon">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="2" y="2" width="196" height="96" style="fill:#dedede;stroke:#555555;stroke-width:2"/></svg>
  </div>
  <span class="headline">Headline in here</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Span takes width and height only when we make it block element. spans are by default displayed inline, which means they don't have a height and width.

So replace,

```
 <span class="headline">Headline in here</span>
```

with,

```
 <div class="headline">Headline in here</div>
```

EDIT 1:

As MiXT4PE pointed out, replace the svg-container with div tag too.

Comment: Ok, exchanged both span containers with div, still the height I get returned from $('.headline').height(); is 0. I tried other elements on page – since I thought it might be some behaviour of this headline-element which prevents jquery to deliver the height, but it never gives me the real height. Sometimes it returns 2, sometimes -2

Comment: I checked the above code in jsfiddle and I was getting the expected results. Please post the rest of your code so that I can see where your problem lies.